# Creating a Google Calendar event in VB

Tags: vb.net, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create a Google Calendar Event in Visual Basic using the Google Api v3.

I've managed to authenticate and get events from the calendar but I'm not sure how to save events and the documentation isn't very helpful.

Here's my current code:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO


Imports System.Threading

Imports Google.Apis.Calendar.v3
Imports Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data
Imports Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.EventsResource
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Util.Store
Imports Google.Apis.Requests


Public Class ClsGoogle


    '' Calendar scopes which is initialized on the main method.
    Dim scopes As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

    '' Calendar service.
    Dim service As CalendarService

    Public CalEvents As List(Of [Event]) = New List(Of [Event])     'List of events in the calendar

    Sub New()       'Classes constructor, to authenticate with google servers everytime an object is created
        Authenticate()
    End Sub

    Private Function Authenticate()     'Function that gets authenticates with google servers

        ' Add the calendar specific scope to the scopes list.
        scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar)


        Dim credential As UserCredential
        Using stream As New FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None,
                    New FileDataStore("Calendar.VB.Sample")).Result
        End Using

        ' Create the calendar service using an initializer instance
        Dim initializer As New BaseClientService.Initializer()
        initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential
        initializer.ApplicationName = "VB.NET Calendar Sample"
        service = New CalendarService(initializer)
        Return 0        
    End Function




    Sub GetCalendar(MinDate As Date, Optional MaxDate As Date = Nothing)

        Dim list As IList(Of CalendarListEntry) = service.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items()     'List of all the google calendars the user has
        Dim EventRequest As ListRequest = service.Events.List(list("0").Id)     'Specifies which google calendar to perform the query

        EventRequest.TimeMin = MinDate      'Specifies the minimum date to look for in the query

        If Not MaxDate = Nothing Then
            EventRequest.TimeMax = MaxDate      'Specifies the maximum date to look for in the query
        End If
        For Each CalendarEvent As Data.Event In EventRequest.Execute.Items  'For each event in the google calendar add to CalEvents
            CalEvents.Add(CalendarEvent)
        Next
    End Sub


    Sub UpdateCalendar()
        Dim CalendarEvent As New Data.Event
        Dim StartDateTime As New Data.EventDateTime
        Dim A As Date
        A = "19/11/2014 12:00"
        StartDateTime.DateTime = A
        Dim b As Date
        b = A.AddHours(2)
        Dim EndDateTime As New Data.EventDateTime
        EndDateTime.DateTime = b
        CalendarEvent.Start = StartDateTime
        CalendarEvent.End = EndDateTime
        CalendarEvent.Id = System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString
        CalendarEvent.Description = "Test"


        Dim Request As New InsertRequest(service, CalendarEvent, service.Events.List(list("0").Id))
        Request.CreateRequest()
        Request.Execute()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) new event

```
service.Events.Insert(CalendarEvent, service.Events.List(list("0").Id).Execute()
```

2) delete event (id is event id)

' search id event

```
Dim id As String = Getevent_id(oggetto, data, ora)
service.Events.Delete(service.Events.List(list("0").Id, id).Execute()
```

3) update event (id is event id)

' search id event

```
Dim id As String = Getevent_id(oggetto, data, ora)
service.Events.Update(CalendarEvent, service.Events.List(list("0").Id, id).Execute()
```

`------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Public Function Getevent_id(testo As String, data As String, ora As String)

        Dim EventRequest As ListRequest = service.Events.List(service.Events.List(list("0").Id))
        '
        EventRequest.Q = testo
        '
        For Each CalendarEvent As Data.Event In EventRequest.Execute.Items  
            Dim stringa As String = data.ToString & " " & ora.ToString
            If CalendarEvent.Start.DateTime.ToString <> Nothing Then
                If CalendarEvent.Start.DateTime.ToString.Substring(0, stringa.Length) = data.ToString & " " & ora.ToString Then
                    ' ok
                    Return CalendarEvent.Id
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Return 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find an example on adding a recurring event in c#, which is not very different in the way of creating a normal event, it also shouldn't be difficult to change it into VB code.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/recurringevents.